# Retrieve POST Request Body of Http client in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, httpclient, http-request

Any way to retrieve the POST Request Body of Http Client in C#? I just want to check in my UT if my extension method is adding it properly to the request or not. This function is not doing any justice to it.

```
public static async Task<string> AddPostRequestBody<T>(this HttpClient httpclient, string RequestUrl, T classobject)
    {
        string json_body = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classobject);
        HttpRequestMessage RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, RequestUrl);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.PostAsync(RequestUrl, new StringContent(json_body));
        response = httpclient.SendAsync(RequestMessage).Result;
        string outputresult = await response.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return outputresult;
    }
```

Please help !

Comment: Just inspect the outgoing request with Fiddler?

Comment: Or use the _Network_  tab in you browser web tools?

Comment: I am writing a UT for my extension method so I need some way to retrieve the body in code.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a DelegatingHandler (which I've used in implementing HMAC to hash the content and add the necessary authorization headers), this will let you access the content.

```
CustomDelegatingHandler customDelegatingHandler = new CustomDelegatingHandler();
HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(customDelegatingHandler);

public class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            byte[] content = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            // Do what you need with the content here
        }

        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fine that you decided to go about your problem in a different way, but I at least still answered your original question, even if your question ended up getting changed by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I got it working with this instead of creating a response, I am directly appending to the request message and retrieving from it. Simple one but initially in the posted question, I made it complicated by adding the json string to response.

```
public static string AddPostRequestBody<T>(this HttpClient httpclient, string requestUrl, T classObject)
    {
        string jsonBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classObject);
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody);
        string requestBody = requestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return requestBody;           
    }
```