# Reading body of Http Request from Http Client as some sort of collection in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient

My end goal is getting a sign of the headers + body of an http request that I'm about to send.

I'm using a `DelegatingHandler` to intercept the request before it is sent in order to obtain the headers + the body of whatever request I'm sending with this client and not just 1 specific request.

The API that I'm dealing with requires the header and body fields to be ordered in ASCII order and then combined to a single string like =&= and so on for the whole request, so I have to extract the headers and the body and run the algorithm on them.

My main issue here is that I have yet to find a way to extract the body of the request as a `KeyValuePair` or a collection of some sort.

I have managed to get the headers using

```
var headers = request.Headers.ToList();
```

which outputs a `List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>` which is fine to deal with.

but i have yet to find a similar way to get the body

I have tried using

```
var body = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

but this returns a single string from a stream, which will hinder the process of sorting it then hashing it with the headers.

note that i have read [Retrieve POST Request Body of Http client in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093817/retrieve-post-request-body-of-http-client-in-c-sharp) and it doesn't seem to be asking for the same thing I am asking for, and their solution seems similar to what I previously tried with no avail.

Comment: It isn't clear how the body is structured. Ideally, you would deserialize the response into whatever shape it is sent in.

Comment: @DavidL I'm trying to keep it generic if there's a way to do so, I could get the body before the request is sent through the client but in that case i believe i won't be getting all the headers, no?